# Handling multiple tables using List<> in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, multiple-resultsets

Here is my prob, am new to mvc,

I have used a List<> to get Data from **Store Procedure** as below,

```
List<Sp_MM_GetDetails_Result> lDetails = objDB.Sp_MM_GetDetails(ArticleURL).ToList();
```

Its working fine for me, but my SP returning **2 table of data**. However my List<> taking only **first table's data**.

what should do if I wanted to get data from **second table?**

In C#, we can done this by using

```
DataSet.Table[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the raw SqlCommand and execute Translate to map to the matching types.

Check this sample

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/data/jj691402